# Remote access to Google Cloud SQL from Comcast network

Tags: remote-access, google-cloud-sql

I cannot access the Google Cloud SQL from my comcast network at home, even after trying every type of allow ip settings.  However it works if I access the Google Cloud SQL via my iPhone, or from another site like a coffee shop.  I can check my IP address, add it to the allowed hosts, and it works, just not from Comcast.

Here is one possible issue:
When I Google "What is my IP", it returns:  **Your public IP address is 2601:2:4f00:5d1:bd3b:178:xxxx:xxx** -  So could Comcast be using IP6 now?  I tried but cannot set an IP6 address in the "Access Control->Authorized Networks setting in the Google Developers Console.

I have 100 megabit service at home via Comcast, so coffee shops or iphone usage is too slow!  Help!!

Comment: Does http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test also reports only your IPv6 addresses? Comcast is providing dual-stack, both IPv4 and IPv6 so it should be able to access the instance once you figure out your IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Comcast provides a 'dual stack' system with IPv4 and IPv6. Find out your IPv4 address at http://ip4.me/ and authorize that address. When you connect to Cloud SQL's IPv4 public address that will be the source address.